# How to solve two inequalities that which simultaneous answers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have two inequalities here, and I must find the answer for both of them simultaneously (joint answer):

$\left\{
 \begin{aligned}
\dfrac{2}{x-3} \gt \dfrac{5}{x+6}  \\
\dfrac{1}{3} \lt \dfrac{1}{x-2}
\end{aligned}
\right.$

Please give me some hints and I'll do the rest. But if you have full time you can show me how to do it. Anyway, I can't find anything like this question on the Internet. I can solve one inequality, but two inequalities with a joint answer is new to me.

Comment: What I would suggest is to solve both inequalities separately. This should give you a range for which $x$ satisfies inequality 1, and a range for which $x$ satisfies inequality 2. Taking the intersection of these ranges gives you the range of all $x$ which satisfy both inequality 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first it's $$\frac{2}{x-3}-\frac{5}{x+6}>0$$ or
$$\frac{x-9}{(x-3)(x+6)}<0,$$
which gives $$(-\infty,-6)\cup(3,9).$$

Solve the second inequality by the same way.

Can you end it now?

I got the following answer:
$$(3,5)$$

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider the inequalties

$(1) \quad \dfrac{2}{x-3} \gt \dfrac{5}{x+6} $

and

$(2) \quad \dfrac{1}{3} \lt \dfrac{1}{x-2} $.

Then compute the set $L_1$ of the solutions of $(1)$ and the set $L_2$ of the solutions of $(2)$.

The set of solutions of

$\left\{
 \begin{aligned}
\dfrac{2}{x-3} \gt \dfrac{5}{x+6}  \\
\dfrac{1}{3} \lt \dfrac{1}{x-2} 
\end{aligned}
\right.$

is given by $L_1 \cap L_2.$

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the second inequality. There are two cases here:

- $x>2$: then$$\frac13<\frac1{x-2}\iff\frac{x-2}3<1\iff x-2<\frac13;$$
- $x<2$: then$$\frac13<\frac1{x-2}\iff\frac{x-2}3>1\iff x-2>\frac13.$$

Now, you do the same thing with the other inequality. Finally, you take the intersection of your answers.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{x-3} \gt \dfrac{5}{x+6} \\
\dfrac{1}{3} \lt \dfrac{1}{x-2} 
\end{cases}$$

We start by solving each inequality by itself. I will assume you can already do this, so we now have

$$\begin{cases}x<-6,\ 3<x<9\\
2<x<5\end{cases}$$

If we imagine drawing these on a number line then we get the following:

```
  -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 --|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--
<--o                          o-----------------o
                           o--------o
```

From here it is very clear that the only numbers where it is true for both of the inequalities is $3<x<5$.